# Problema com xdebug no vsCode

Tags: php, apache, servidor, xdebug

Até ontem funcionava normal, agora tá sempre retornando esse erro no meio do processo no debug console:

```
   XDebugError: command is not available
        at new Response (/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:56:19)
        at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:611:20)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at fulfilled (/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:4:58)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5) {
      code: 5,
      name: 'XDebugError'
    }
    connection 9: read ECONNRESET
    XDebugError: command is not available
        at new Response (/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:56:19)
        at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:611:20)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at fulfilled (/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:4:58)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5) {
      code: 5,
      name: 'XDebugError'
    }
    connection 10: read ECONNRESET
    XDebugError: command is not available
        at new Response (/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:56:19)
        at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:611:20)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at fulfilled (/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:4:58)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5) {
      code: 5,
      name: 'XDebugError'
    }
    connection 11: read ECONNRESET
```

Esse é o `launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000, 
            "pathMappings": {
                "/Volumes/SDCARD/projects/myproject": "${workspaceRoot}",
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

No servidor parece normal:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No PHP.ini também:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então uma pessoa disse nos fóruns para colocar "stopOnEntry": true, no `launch.json`, e daí retornou:

`Unable to open 'index.php': Unable to read file '/Volumes/SDCARD/projects/myproject/public/index.php' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/Volumes/SDCARD/projects/myproject/public/index.php')`

Então removi o SD CARD e coloquei novamente, e ele caiu na primeira linha desse arquivo `index.php`, mas quando coloco `stopOnEntry` para false, ele voltar a dar aquele primeiro erro no terminal XDebugError..., eu queria que ele caísse na linha onde eu marquei com a bolinha vermelha, que é onde está minha requisição, e não no primeiro arquivo onde ele inicializa o framework.